# Travel mate or Traveling mate? Which one is a correct english phrase?

Tags: word-choice

Today I ran into phrase "**Traveling mate**". I searched through online dictionaries but didin't find an entry for "Traveling mate" or "**Travel mate**". I am curious to know which one is a correct english word?

> 1. **Traveling mate:** My father is a perfect **traveling mate**.
> 2. **Travel mate:** In most cases, this allows Paul to pick up a **travel mate** on his way into the city.
> 3. Travel-mate: I can't remember where I saw it!!

Comment: Could you edit to give a bit more context? Is this a person or is it a name for some item intended to help travellers?

Comment: @mdewey Thank you. It is about a person who travels with you.

Comment: Neither expression is familiar to me: I would say _travelling companion_ (I use British spelling of "travelling"). _Travel(l)ling mate_ is understandable to me, in that sense. When I hear _travel mate_ it sounds to me like something somebody wants to sell you to help your journey.

Comment: @ColinFine that sounds like an answer to me if you have time to post it

Answer (score 2):

1. Traveling mate
2. Travel mate
3. Travel-mate

Any of those choices are possible, because "travel mate" is not a set phrase found in the dictionary. The word "travel" is in the position of an adjective modifying "mate". The resulting expression means "travel(ing) companion", which is also not found in the dictionary as one entry.